# How to plot a satellite's orbit around Earth in MATLAB?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, physics, astrodynamics

Given orbit height, mass and initial velocity how should I plot a satellite's orbit in MATLAB? I was hoping to use verlet integration (I need to implement a solver) possibly the velocity-verlet. I would also like to develop this into a model that also includes the Moon but this was a stretch goal.

Comment: If the mass of your orbiter is much smaller than the Earth's, then it is irrelevant for the orbit. If you want calculate the orbital parameters from an initial state, you would need not just the initial velocity, but also the location and direction of travel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the comment above mentions, you wouldn't need mass of the satellite unless its a Deathstar. Also, you would need the initial values of elements you want to propagate.

Since you mention that you want to **plot** a satellite's orbit in MATLAB, in the most basic sense (since you haven't mentioned other keplerian elements), I take it that you know the altitude of the orbit, and want to know where the satellite will be, i.e. the true anomaly *theta* at a given time *t*. (whatever inclination, RAAN etc.)

If that's the case, assuming a circular orbit, the vis-viva equation gives:
$$
V = \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{r}}
$$
Where r is the radius of circular orbit. Since rate of change of true anomaly *d_theta* would be nothing but the angular velocity, using $\omega = \frac{V}{r}$, we can see that

$$
\omega = \frac{d(theta)} {dt} = {\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{r^3}}}
$$

Now you can provide the initial value and propagate with whatever integrator you prefer. Here's an example I wrote with a very basic integrator.

```
    clear;
    clc;
    
    %true_anomaly = [];
    time          = [];
    x             = [];
    y             = [];
    
    theta  = deg2rad(0); %initial value of true anomaly
    dt     = 1;          %temporal resolution
     
    rE = 6471; %average radius of the Earth km
    h  = 400;  %assumed altitude of the circular orbit km
    
    r  = h + rE; %radius of the circular orbit km
    mu = 3.986e5;%graviational parameter of the Earth
    
    for t=0:dt:10000
    
     d_theta = sqrt( mu/(r^3) );   %equation
     theta   = theta + d_theta*dt; %integration
    
     %true_anomaly = [true_anomaly,rad2deg(theta)];
     time          = [time,t];
     x             = [x, r*cos(theta)];
     y             = [y, r*sin(theta)];
    
    end
    
    plot3(x,y,time);
```

Hope I've done this correctly. It results in plotting the orbit in an Earth centric frame. (With time on the vertical axis.)

[image]

If you plan to plot the orbit with all the elements or want to plot a ground plot and so on, then get the initial values and use the support files in [this MATLAB Answers page.](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/499567-plot-the-orbit-of-a-satellite)

Hope this helps!